# Is This a Good Design Choice?

Tags: c++, templates, void-pointers

I'm writing a program in OpenGL, and there's going to be custom events that are going to happen, ex. when a player hits an obstacle or takes a step. What I want to do is:

Have a singleton class named something like "EventBroadcaster." The broadcaster will get fed events from around the program. Then, when it receives an event, it will send it to all the listeners ("EventListener" objects) with a void* containing a struct which holds the event's information. The EventListener objects can then use their own custom callback function to handle the different types of events. Now, I want to avoid using void* if it all possible, so...

...question is, how can I do this with a template interface?

Comment: Why can't you inherit all events from a single interface?

Comment: You might want to look at the observer design pattern (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting everything to void* and then back is error prone. Take a look at [boost::signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/signals.html) or some [other](http://sigslot.sourceforge.net) signal/slot library. It might help you avoid throwing away the type information.

A class can expose a slot and then invoke it. For example there could be a slot like `void PlayerMovedTo( Point position )`. Other classes can connect to that slot and will be notified when the signal is sent.

Here's a rough sketch of how the signal/slot mechanism works in general:

```
class Game {
public:
  Signal<void (float, float)> PlayerMovedTo;

  void update() {
    if ( downKeyPressed ) {
       y += 10;
       PlayerMovedTo( x, y ); // Tell everyone about it
    }
  }
};


class Mine {
public:
  Mine() {
    // There can be many mines, all connected to the one signal.
    game.PlayerMovedTo.connect( this, &Mine::playerMoved );
  }

  void playerMoved( float x, float y ) {
    if ( distance( this->x, this->y, x, y ) < 10 ) {
      boom();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This is a clean, templated solution.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is to avoid the type information being discarded because you're using a void pointer, you might want to look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any/s02.html)